# include in $ How do I embed include in the code?

Tags: php, include

How do I embed include in the code?

**I want this page (tabtab.php) to be displayed before $content
Page tabtab.php is not currently displayed with this code .
**

```
if(!empty($mp3Link)) { 

 $linkHtml = '
<a class="w3-black" href="#ucomment">com</a>   
 
' . include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/tabtab.php') . ' 
     
   ';
                
     
};

        $mp3Info = 
            
            "<h2><p><span>1 : </span><span>$mp3_caption</span></h2></p>";
            

        return $imageTag.$mp3Info."<br/>".$playerTag."<br/>".$linkHtml.$content;
    }

    return $content;

}
add_filter('the_content', 'append_mp3_file');
```

Comment: wrap you php code between **<?php ... ?>**

Comment: <?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_ads.php');  ?>

Comment: In this case, too, the site does not load

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI, no. That will just output '<?php include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_ads.php'); ?>' as a string.

Comment: The site does not load

Comment: @MohammedYassineCHABLI The OP is *already* in php. @sa eu You want to include the contents of that file inside the `$html` variable?

Comment: yes   I edited my questions, you can see

Answer (score 0):

You need to make the include function part of PHP and not the string,

```php
if(!empty($mp3Link)) {

    $linkHtml = '



<a class="w3-black" href="#ucomment">comen</a>   
<span id="ucomment"></span>  
' . include (TEMPLATEPATH . '/single_ads.php') . '   **// I want to embed it here**


   ';
      
};
```

Comment: No error this time, but    single_ads.php     page not displayed (not loaded)

Comment: Are you able to share more of the code? Is the file not being loaded because if can't be found?

Comment: File exists but does not display  ... I added image in the article

Comment: I want this page to be displayed before $ content